# simple data insertion using realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm an newbie in realm-swift. Trying to do an simple data insertion in realm DB.
I'm getting following warning:-

```
WARNING: An RLMRealm instance was deallocated during a write transaction and
all pending changes have been rolled back. Make sure to retain a reference
to the RLMRealm for the duration of the write transaction.
```

Here is my code :-

```
    //
//  Dog.swift
//  RealmDemo
//
//  Created by RIPA SAHA on 20/07/16.
//  Copyright Â© 2016 RIPA SAHA. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class Dog {

    dynamic var name = ""

    dynamic var age = ""

}



//
//  ViewController.swift
//  RealmDemo
//
//  Created by RIPA SAHA on 19/07/16.
//  Copyright Â© 2016 RIPA SAHA. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        let myDog = Dog()
        myDog.name = "puppies"
        myDog.age = "5"


        // Get the default Realm
        let realm = try! Realm()

        // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
        realm.beginWrite()


             realm.add(myDog)


        /*realm.add(myDog)
        realm.commitWrite()*/



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you please share the code for the write transaction that's generating this warning?

Comment: @bdash this is my code link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/25676acde9cd4adf29dec4dc5a614615

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this example:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Dog : Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your write code as follow:

```
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(myDog)
}
```

This should fix the problem

Comment: You're not closing the transaction, uncomment realm.commitWrite() line

Comment: Can you post the error log? Try replacing the .beginWrite()/.commitWrite() with the code I provided

Comment: " Call can throw but it is not marked with try and the error is not handled" == this error

Comment: Use the try! block I provided, that is for ignoring the errors throw

Comment: But after doing below:-
do{ 
try! realm.commitwrite() 
} 
giving " thread 1: signal sigart" error in appdelegate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117886/discussion-between-luca-nicoletti-and-ripa).